# How to get selected value of bootstrap dropdown button

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, dropdown

I'm new in laravel and bootstrap ,i need to get the selected value of a dropdown button of bootstrap and send this value to my database
Below the code of dropdown list button :

```xml
<div class="dropdown col-md-6" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" name="qty" type="button" id="dropdownMenu2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Quantity %
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu2">
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">100%</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">75%</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">50%</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">25%</button>
        <button class="dropdown-item" type="button">0%</button>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
```

This is the related function in controller :

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $mouvement = new Mouvement();
    $mouvement->rmepn    = $request->input('rmepn');
    $mouvement->rmsn     = $request->input('rmsn');
    $mouvement->rmspn    = $request->input('rmspn');
    $mouvement->location = $request->input('location');
    $mouvement->qty      = $request->input('qty');
    $mouvement->feederid = $request->user()->name;
    $mouvement->project  = $request->input('project');
    $mouvement->rmtype   = $request->input('rmtype');
    $mouvement->ordernr  = $request->input('ordernr');
    $mouvement->save();
}
```

[image: Input interface]

Comment: Why not just use a `select` element?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a dropdown you should just use either a `<select>` element or radio inputs.

Bootstrap 4 Docs provide a few examples

```xml
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="quantityPercentageInput">Quantity %</label>
    <select id="quantityPercentageInput" name="quantityPercentage" class="form-control">
        <option value="100%">100%</option>
        <option value="75%">75%</option>
        <option value="50%">50%</option>
        <option value="25%">25%</option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```xml
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="quantityPercentageInput" name="quantityPercentage" class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Quantity %</option>
        <option value="100%">100%</option>
        <option value="75%">75%</option>
        <option value="50%">50%</option>
        <option value="25%">25%</option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```xml
<div class="form-group">
    <select id="quantityPercentageInput" name="quantityPercentage" class="custom-select">
        <option selected>Quantity %</option>
        <option value="100%">100%</option>
        <option value="75%">75%</option>
        <option value="50%">50%</option>
        <option value="25%">25%</option>
        <option value="0%">0%</option>
    </select>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">Example invalid custom select feedback</div>
</div>
```

```php
// selected value: 
$request->input('quantityPercentage')
```